# Extracting .docx files with Tika in Apache Solr gives NoSuchMethod error

Tags: solr, apache-poi

I have a Solr 4.0 module in my project (basically, a maven web project with all the solr dependencies). It worked pretty well, including content extraction and everything.

But, when I tested it with a `.docx` document, It gives me the following error:

```
13:50:34,468 ERROR [org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-9) 
null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackagePart.getRelatedPart(Lorg/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackageRelationship;)
Lorg/apache/poi/openxml4j/opc/PackagePart;
```

I tried to manually add the `openxml4j` dependency to the project. I've downloaded the sources and looked at it, the `PackagePart#getRelatedPart` really doesn't exist.

What is this error? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

---

#### EDIT

I noticed that `poi-ooxml` already had those classes inside it. Cool, but I also inspected those sources, and still doesn't have the needed method in the `PackagePart` class.

BTW: I tried to add `openxml4j` version `1.0-beta`.

Comment: Where did you get your POI jars from, Maven or manually? Could you perhaps have two copies of the POI jars from different versions on your classpath?

Comment: Maven, but yeah, I had. I just run a `mvn dependency:tree` and found another project using an old version, fixed it, and than it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a jarhell related issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, "jarhell related" was the clue I needed!

My project had POI jars prior to import of the Tika app jar, which includes its own POI jars.  I deleted the standalone POI jars, and then Tika was able to handle DOCX Word 2013 file without error.

Now hopefully I won't run into a situation where I need both! :|

Comment: I think it would be better if you comment this in the right answer and/or upvote it.